# The Video Output on my screen is very lagging

Tags: graphics, video, gpu-driver, vga, pci

For VGA bus there is no kernel driver in use..
The Output of the `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|Display';` is as follows

```
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Mullins [Radeon R4/R5 Graphics]
    Subsystem: Dell Mullins [Radeon R4/R5 Graphics]
    Kernel modules: radeon, amdgpu
00:01.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Kabini HDMI/DP Audio
```

Output of `grep radeon /etc/modprobe.d/*` is as follows

```
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-framebuffer.conf:blacklist radeonfb
/etc/modprobe.d/fglrx-core.conf:blacklist radeon
/etc/modprobe.d/fglrx-core.conf:alias radeon off
/etc/modprobe.d/fglrx-core.conf:alias lbm-radeon off
```

Name of Processor :- amd a6-6310 apu with amd radeon r4 graphics

RAM 4GB

DELL INSPIRON 64bit

Vesrion: 20.04LTS

Desktop Environment: GNOME

output of `inxi -G` is as following

```
    Graphics:
  Device-1: AMD Mullins [Radeon R4/R5 Graphics] driver: N/A 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.13 driver: ati,fbdev 
  unloaded: modesetting,radeon,vesa resolution: 1366x768~76Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 13.0.0 256 bits) 
  v: 4.5 Mesa 22.0.0-devel (git-4a38ed8 2021-11-11 focal-oibaf-ppa)
```

Comment: please [edit] your question with version of Ubuntu in use and desktop environment.

Comment: Edited as 20.04 LTS and GNOME DE

Comment: Please add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|Display'; grep radeon /etc/modprobe.d/*` command. As text please.

Comment: edited plz check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You tried to install obsolete `fglrx` driver. It blacklisted `radeon` as you can see in `/etc/modprobe.d/fglrx-core.conf`.

The solution is to remove it by

```
sudo apt purge 'fglrx*'
```

If you have problems with removing that package, you can simply remove that file:

```
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/fglrx-core.conf
```

Comment: Is there any special care to be taken during purge operation , As it won't cause any problem

Comment: There shouldn't be any problems. You installed a wrong package somehow.

Comment: Thank you so so much, Now all the animations, 1080p videos are working like a butter, Thank you so much, What can i do for you

Comment: You are welcome.